# Is there a way to wrap a SharedWorker in a Promise?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I tried to use `webworker-promise` to wrap a `SharedWorker` in a promise based way.  But that doesn't seem to be working.  Is there a way to make this work or is there some other library available?

```
import WebworkerPromise from 'webworker-promise'

const worker = new WebworkerPromise(new SharedWorker('worker.ts'));

dex.js:67 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this._worker.postMessage is not a function
    at index.js:67:20
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Worker.postMessage (index.js:64:12)
```

Comment: `webworker-promise` is for node.js and not the browser.

Comment: From reading their docs it seems it should work for both.